# Error loading DBPedia Turtle in Virtuoso with Docker

Tags: docker, dbpedia, virtuoso, turtle-rdf

I downloaded DBPedia turtle-files with their extraction framework (https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework).

Then I used the docker image `tenforce/virtuoso:1.3.2-virtuoso7.2.2` after extracting all `ttl.bz2` to a `toLoad` folder.

After the full load, I checked `isql` with `select * from DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST;` and got an error from one of the files:

> 2 2019.2.2 11:31.43 69876000 2019.2.2 11:31.44 521623000 0 NULL 37000
>   [Vectorized Turtle loader] SP029: TURTLE RDF loader, line 172395:
>   syntax error

The virtuoso endpoint (http://localhost:8890/sparql) is online, but the queries don't return correct results.

Do you know what I can do to correct this error?

UPDATE: newer `tenforce/virtuoso:1.3.2-virtuoso7.2.5.1` and `openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7` were also tested giving the same result.

UPDATE 2: Line 172395 of that file seems ok: `<http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Reino_de_Roma> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/governmentType> <http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Monarquia> <http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reino_de_Roma?oldid=53119289&ns=0> .`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in [your duplicate post on github](https://github.com/tenforce/docker-virtuoso/issues/25) --

> I would start by using [`tenforce/virtuoso:latest` or `tenforce/virtuoso:virtuoso7.2.5` or `tenforce/virtuoso:1.3.2-virtuoso7.2.5`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tenforce/virtuoso), all of which should be based on [Virtuoso 7.2.5.1 (from August 2018)](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/17c4ba1d5825822d8380ef8d9f978e2d57f4768f), rather than the rather elderly `tenforce/virtuoso:1.3.2-virtuoso7.2.2` which is based on the similarly elderly [Virtuoso 7.2.2 (from December 2015)](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/359f26c55b98669e08fcaa9745e017759d276312).

Comment: I'm sorry for the duplication. I tried using the image tenforce/virtuoso:1.3.2-virtuoso7.2.5.1 and the problem persists.

Comment: Next would be to try with the latest [OpenLink official docker image, `openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7`](https://hub.docker.com/r/openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7), which is based on Virtuoso 7.2.6-rc1 (from December 2018).  If issues still persist, I suggest you come to the (also public, but more focused) [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com) where we can work more directly with you.

Comment: @TailTed same problem with the same line using virtuoso-opensource-7. I think there might be something wrong with this turtle file extracted.

Comment: @StaticX - Yes. I notice you said you extracted "all ttl.bz2 to a toLoad file" -- is that one giant TTL file? If so, I'd like to see the 10 or so lines around 172395 (so, 172390-172400). Also note that generally speaking, you'll be better off loading a bunch of smaller files with our [bulk-load tool](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader), which would also help narrow the issue (and so, help with getting the original fixed).

Comment: I am sorry, it was just a writing mistake (updated). Where you read "file" is "folder". There is one TTL for each ttl.bz2 in the toLoad folder.

Comment: OK, so I'd like to see those lines from that file (it shouldn't need to be the whole file), either added to your question within a code-fence here, or attached to your question on the other site.

Comment: Updated with the line. I don't see any difference with this line in specific.

Comment: Well, it's not valid Turtle, which only has 3 elements per line (Subject, Predicate, Object). That might be a line of [N-Quad](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/) serialization.

Comment: that is a bit strange, since the complete file has this structure. And there is no error on the previous lines. Another line example: <http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Afeganistão> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/officialLanguage> <http://pt.dbpedia.org/resource/Língua_dari> .

Comment: Your new example has *three* elements (the things wrapped in angle-brackets) on the line, not four. The markup needed to show this clearly will not work in this comment thread; please look to [the github thread](https://github.com/tenforce/docker-virtuoso/issues/25#issuecomment-466413391).

Comment: I see.. there might be a problem with my dbpedia extraction then.

Comment: Depending on your project, you might consider [loading and working from the DBpedia dumps](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/develop/datasets)...

Comment: Unfortunately, I need more up-to-date data. But I managed to get it working by using some post processing commands before Virtuoso load:  https://github.com/dbpedia/databus-maven-plugin/blob/master/dbpedia/rapandsort You can change your answer for me to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Your `databus-maven-plugin` link 404s, and it's unclear what post-processing commands you ran. It might be better to post these details to your github issue, with full markup and detail, not limited by the comment length and markup here...